# Javascript if else problem

Tags: javascript

My `if-else` is not working, I think that I have a variable issue. When I look at the value of `x` it is not what is entered in the text field. Any Ideas?

```
function guess() {

    var x = document.getElementById("magic");

    var word = "please";
    if (x == word) {
        alert("You entered the magic word!");
    } else {
        alert("Please try again!");
    }
}

<form>
    What is the magic word?<br />
    <input type="text" id="magic" onchange="guess()" />
</form>
```

Comment: x = object, you will need to use .value in order to compare with word.

Comment: try `var x = document.getElementById("magic").value`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not getting the value. Use this:

```
var x =document.getElementById("magic").value;
```

Answer (score 4):

You want:

```
var x = document.getElementById("magic").value;
```

Also, `onchange` won't work, you'll need to use `onkeyup`, although `onblur` is probably more sane:

```
What is the magic word?<br />
<input type="text" id="magic" onblur="guess()" />

function guess() {
    var x = document.getElementById("magic").value;

    var word = "please";

    if (x == word) {
        alert("You entered the magic word!");
    } else {
        alert("Please try again!");
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6uAhq/

Comment: Are you sure you'd want it to barrage the user with `alert`s? (`onkey*` would alert "Please try again!" for every letter they typed until they typed it all in correctly)

Comment: Yeah, `onblur` is probably better. I was thinking of the `onchange`, not the application.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check against the actual value of the "magic" element, e.g.:

```
var x = document.getElementById("magic").value;
```

I'm assuming "magic" is an input.